# Routing error on NavigationMixin logout action in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am developing an Experience builder site with an LWR template. I am trying to create a logout button using the standard code for it:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: "comm__loginPage",
    attributes: {
      actionName: 'logout'
    }
});
```

But when this part is executed I receive this routing error:

```
A URL cannot be created to navigate to route "{"type":"comm__loginPage","attributes":{"actionName":"logout"}}"
```

I also tried to logout using `/secur/logout.jsp` URL but I redirects me to login.salesforce.com page and not the login page for my experience site

Does anyone has any thoughts how this can be fixed or any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Does your site have a prefix? I.e. in the site URL, is it .com/s or .com/[prefix]/s? If the latter, the logout problem may be fixed by prepending that suffix to the "/secur/logout.jsp" page if not done already.